# How to open a new webpage with selenium (and close the older) in Python?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, geckodriver

I want to do some web-scraping from a website with selenium in Python 2.7, wait a little bit, and after close the browser + close the geckodriver.exe (because I don't want to open millions of browser pages and .exe files)

Is there any way I can do this?

My code with comments:

```js
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import urllib2
import unicodecsv as csv
import os
import sys
import io
import time
import datetime
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import MySQLdb
import re
import contextlib
import selenium.webdriver.support.ui as ui

#I am create a new csv file
filename=r'output.csv'

resultcsv=open(filename,"wb")
output=csv.writer(resultcsv, delimiter=';',quotechar = '"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC, encoding='latin-1')

#I am opening the website with selenium (js website)
profile=webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference("intl.accept_languages","en-us")
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile)
driver.get("https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/bud/arrivals")
time.sleep(10)
html_source=driver.page_source
soup=BeautifulSoup(html_source,"html.parser")
print soup

#HERE I AM WEBSCRAPING THE INFORMATIONS WHAT I NEEDED AND 
#AFTER I AM WRITING IT INTO THIS CSV FILE.
 
output.writerows(datatable)
 
resultcsv.close()

#AND MY QUESTION START HERE. I WANT TO CLOSE THIS SESSEION,
#WAIT A LITTLE, FOR EXAMPLE 10 SEC, BECAUSE IT IS NEEDED SOME TIME TO WEB-
#SCRAPING DATAES AFTER THIS CLOSE THE GECKODRIVER + FIREFOX, AND AFTER 
#REPEAT THIS CODE WITH A NEW WEBSITE. IS IT POSSIBLE?
```

## Updated code - nutmeg64

I get this error message:

> File "C:/Python27/air17.py", line 43, in 
>       scrape(urls)
>     File "C:/Python27/air17.py", line 28, in scrape
>       table = soup.find('table', { "class" : "table table-condensed table-hover data-table m-n-t-15" })
>   NameError: global name 'soup' is not defined

```js
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import urllib2
import unicodecsv as csv
import os
import sys
import io
import time
import datetime
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import MySQLdb
import re
import contextlib
import selenium.webdriver.support.ui as ui

filename=r'output.csv'

resultcsv=open(filename,"wb")
output=csv.writer(resultcsv, delimiter=';',quotechar = '"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC, encoding='latin-1')

def scrape(urls):
    browser = webdriver.Firefox()
    for url in urls:
        browser.get(url)
        html = browser.page_source
        soup=BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")
        table = soup.find('table', { "class" : "table table-condensed table-hover data-table m-n-t-15" })
        datatable=[]
        for record in table.find_all('tr', class_="hidden-xs hidden-sm ng-scope"):
            temp_data = []
            for data in record.find_all("td"):
                temp_data.append(data.text.encode('latin-1'))
            datatable.append(temp_data)
 
        output.writerows(datatable)
 
        resultcsv.close()
        time.sleep(10) 
        browser.quit()

urls = ["https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/bud/arrivals", "https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/fco/arrivals"]
scrape(urls)
```

Comment: It's quite simple. You have 2 choices, 1: close the browser and then start a new one. 2: use the existing driver to navigate to a new page. It is really straight-forward. What is your problem?

Comment: The problem is that i am full beginner in the programming world, but i am trying develop my skills ^^ 
So with the solution 1 : after the resultcsv.close() i have to write this : browser.quit() and browser.get(www.google.hu) for example? and that's all?
The 2. solution sound better, the closing browser is an unnecessary thing, how can i navigate to a new page using the existing driver?

Answer (score 0):

Put the selenium part of this in a function and call it with different url. sleep for 10 seconds between iterations.

BTW this is not the Ideal solution. You just need to open selenium once, read the source and then do `browser.get(new_url)`. After all the scraping was done then do `browser.quit()` to release.

for example (very very simplified):

```
def scrape(urls):
    browser = webdriver.Firefox()
    for url in urls:
        browser.get(url)
        html = browser.page_source
        # scrape the html as you like
        # create a csv file for that specific url
        # write results to csv and close it
        time.sleep(10) # <-- not really necessary. scraping and writing to csv is a long enough break
    browser.quit()

urls = ["http://example.com", "http://notarealwebsite.co.uk", "http://lastwebpagetoscrape.com" ]
scrape(urls)
```

Comment: I have got around 10 different website, thats why i choosed this way, to close the selenium and open it again. But your suggestion sounds more simpler. So after the resultcsv.close() i have to write this : browser.quit() and  browser.get(www.google.hu) for example?

Comment: no. don't quit the browser if you have more scraping to do. it does not matter that these are different URLs. I'll add an example to the answer.

Comment: I checked your example, but what part i have to delete in my code and where i have to put it? The web-scraping part is under the html=browser...?

Comment: you put the csv creation outside of the function. do you want to write all results from all urls to the same file? I suggest you try and play with it a little bit yourself. thats the best way to learn.

Comment: Yes, thats why i created outside, i want to write all to the same file

Comment: I tried it, and fixed it, it is working now, but the problem is that it is reading the first link, after close the browser, and stop it whit a long error message (create connection problem). The first link web-scraping table is in the csv, but when it try to start to open the 2. link, it is stopping.

Answer (score 0):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import urllib2
import unicodecsv as csv
import os
import sys
import io
import time
import datetime
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import MySQLdb
import re
import contextlib
import selenium.webdriver.support.ui as ui

#I am create a new csv file

filename=r'output.csv'

resultcsv=open(filename,"wb")
output=csv.writer(resultcsv, delimiter=';',quotechar = '"', 
quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC, encoding='latin-1')
```